# Extracting the exhibitor list (company name) using importxml in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

**Website**
https://www.sialparis.com/Exhibitors/Catalogue-SIAL-Paris/exhibitors

**Used this logic but not working**

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.sialparis.com/Exhibitors/Catalogue-SIAL-Paris/exhibitors","//div/ul/li/a/div/h3")
```

---

```
Xpath - //*[@id="catalog-v2"]/section[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/div[2]/h3
```

Note: If you visit the above website you will see the exhibitor list so with the help of import XML I just want to extract the company name in the google sheet.
I have attached the image for a better understanding.

[image]

Please help me to extract the exhibitor list...

Comment: Title and question don't give clear idea what the author wants to know. Please be specific and share code in a good format to express what you want to know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added the additional comment and attached the image for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript elements are not supported by the import formula of google sheets. you can always check this if you temporarily disable JS for a given site and only what's left can be imported

[image]